# HP4050, Windows 7 64 Bit, Printer Sharing from Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7, hp, drivers

If I use a 'local printer' 'tcp port', I can print to an HP 4050 over the network from a Windows 7 64 bit machine using the Universal HP printer drivers (I happened to use Postscript).

However, the same printer is also shared from a Windows (2003) Server.  On the same Windows 7 machine if I try to add the printer via the share instead of a direct tcp port, I can not get it to work.

If I connect via Windows, it checks Windows Update and fails - no driver.   If I install the HP Universal drivers (tried all 3 - PCL5, PCL6, and PS -- also tried dynamic and traditional) - it also fails saying the driver is not compatible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the (64-bit) driver at the Server.

Comment: I will try that and yes, that makes sense.   However, is there any other option?   Someone told me they were able to use a vista driver on a win 7 machine with an older hp printer (though not the 4050).   I checked and it looks like the vista drivers are the same as the win 7 drivers for the 4050.

Comment: Vista drivers are made the same way Win7 driver are, they aren't guaranteed to be interchangeable, but almost all are. XP and previous drivers were made differently, but Win7 can still run them (usually).